# Connecting dots with lines, thickness depended on attribute value

Tags: qgis, point

[image: how the data]

I am having a point data of in total of 13 destinations within a region. The goal is to present how many people who were in destination "A" also visited the other 12 destinations.

I have this data calculated both in relative and absolute figures. Now, I want to show it on the map.

The data represents relations for a destination X, "Dub". Where **Dub** and **Dub** cross, there is an absolute number of visits for that one destination. The other crossings, eg. Dub-Zad, is a percentage of people that, out of those 316 people, also visited Zad (14% or ca. 51). 
This is all within one region. Now, I want to map this so the line between Zad-Dub is eg. 1.4, Dub-Spl 3.4, Dub-Mak 0.3 and so on. I have, naturally, the coordinates for all of the destinations.

I hope I am more clear now. So, as I said, I have coordinates of those destinations but I don't know how should then the data look and how to use the data to connect the dots the way I want to.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you provide a subset of your attribute table? Also, please decide whether you want to do this in QGIS or ArcGIS.

Comment: Thank you. At this moment, I don't have a subset, I have the data that is described a bit up there. But, it would be something like this:

Comment: 9
9
13
34
5
12
12
5
524
11

Comment: Please, forgive my comments before. Anyway, QGIS is better. So, I have the total number of visits to a destination (524 up there) and those smaller numbers are percentage how many people visited both destination A and that other destination.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your example. Can you provide one complete example in your question? Are the total visits linked to coordinates?

Comment: @Timorche we do this with students and schools showing various attributes using the line width - however -is this 1 example you're working on, or will this be done across many regions?

Comment: Hey guys, I changed the question now and should be much more clear.

Comment: I can make one point that is this Dub one, as for that point I want to visualize relations to other points (destinations). So it would be one layer of Dub with its coordinates, and other 12 points with information on thickness, as seen in the upper table. So those two layers would be needed to connect. I really hope I am now more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute field or expression to define your stroke width:

[image]

As your numbers are likely going to be too large to be used as a width, under the *Expression* submenu, select *Edit* to create a new expression. You can use the field that has your count value and multiply it by say 0.1, for example, to bring it down to a more realistic number that can be used as a width.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't figure it out, I eventually just made lines from the X place to the other 12 places. I added the attribute of thickness, based on the aforementioned percentage of visits (2% = 0.2, 38% = 3.8 and so on). However, this is only applicable when there aren't too many trajectories/lines needed. If anyone knows how to connect points to make lines with special attributes, feel free to post it here.